# FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN's default option

Tags: php

I want my query parameter to be true unless explicitly set otherwise.

```
$a = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'v', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
    array('options' => array('default' => true)));
var_dump($a);
```

However, accessing this script like /test.php?v=false prints `bool(true)`.
Moreover, it always print `bool(true)` on any input.

- Is this expected behavior?
- If so, how can I achieve my purpose in concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE` as an options flag, so that your code instead of being:

`$a = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'v', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, array('options' => array('default' => true)));`

It should be:

`$a = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'v', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, array('options' => array('default' => true), 'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));`

Comment: It prints `NULL` if no parameter is specified like: /test.php. I want `$a` to be true in this case.

Comment: According to function documentation page, the second parameter should be passed by a $_GET index.

Check the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Documentaion also says "When default is set to option, default's value is used if value is not validated." That said, I don't think /test.php?v=false is not validated. Also, Since /test.php fails validation, default value should be used. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have edited my answer, i think you have missed to pass the `flags` in your function call.

Comment: I believe you need to take a look at the provided flags which can be used in order to pass the correct one, as for not being intuitive, i believe this is how the function works.